# Why does Chrome Developer show border-radius when displayed as IE7 or IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, google-chrome-devtools, css

When I override the UA in Chrome Developer by IE7 or IE8, border-radiuses are displayed just fine. But when I open the page in IE8 all corners are square (unsurprisingly). Am I missing something here? Or does it just not work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the UA doesn't make a browser behave like another browser. It just changes the value of the `User-Agent` header sent to the server and to any JavaScript code that checks `navigator.userAgent`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mimicking a browser doesn't really act as the *real* browser! Specially if it's IE!!
2. IE8 and older versions don't support border-radius.
3. Additional notes: if you want to use border-radius for IE9 and IE10, use the long method `border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;` because the `border-radius: 10px;` will for-some-reason might not work!